# How to build parameterized custom layout?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-sdk-1.6, xml-layout

My app is all about manipulating and showing different views of a particular entity.  I have a class called `Item` that defines an entity in my app.  I have created a custom layout that knows how to render a particular version of `Item`s:

```
public class MyItemLayout extends FrameLayout {
    public MyItemLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { ... }
}
```

I would like to be able to reference this in XML:

```
<MyItemLayout .../>
```

What I don't understand yet is:

1. How do I reference this in XML?
2. How do I set the `Item` instance for the element?  I can't do that in XML (or can I?), so how would I do it in code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way for you to reference a custom component (View or ViewGroup) is to have the full package name, like `<com.foo.bar.MyItemLayout>`

One option also to pass data from declaration in XML is using the `AttributeSet` in the constructor. If you set an attribute in XML you can fetch it using the methods from this class (`getFloatValue()` for example).

So:
Step 1: Do something like `<com.foo.bar.MyItemLayout item="xxxx"></com.foo.bar.MyItemLayout>`
Step 2: In `MyItemLayout` constructor call `attrs.getFloatValue()` (or whatever type you wish) to get the data

Hope it helped
JQCorreia